# Trying to use Azure Logs to display Chart with Y-axis customised using custom metrics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

Goal:

I am trying to output a Scatter chart with existing custom metric being pushed through to Azure Logs so that the X-Axis has the timestamp and the Y-Axis has the "Total Duration":

I have the following query:

```
union isfuzzy=true customEvents
| extend monitorDuration = tostring(customDimensions["TotalDuration"])
| where timestamp > datetime("2021-02-23T14:23:16.387Z") and timestamp < datetime("2021-02-24T14:23:16.387Z") and customDimensions contains "TotalDuration"
| order by timestamp asc
| take 100
```

And the following completed output:
[image]

And this shows the following chart:

[image]

However, the Y-Axis shows "itemCount" and what I really want is the duration - in my case 0 - 740 seconds figure that represents my total duration. How do I get the Y-Axis to display the duration? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `monitorDuration` column is a string (from the above KQL query), while a `scatterchart` needs a **numeric** column as the y-axis, i.e., of the type: int, long, decimal or real.

Instead, use [toint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tointfunction). Using `toint(customDimensions["TotalDuration"])` would convert the expression to an integer representation, and then you'd be able to create the chart with duration as the y-axis.

Comment: Thanks very much. That bit appeared to work now for the y-axis.

Comment: @sam0673 Happy to help! Please consider [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you found it helpful. :)